# How do I get the worksheet referenced by a cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function LinkedSheet(rgCell As Range) As Worksheet
'Returns the worksheet that the cell formula references
'Returns nothing if there's no formula
    Dim strFormula As String

    strFormula = rgCell.Cells(1, 1).Formula

    If (strFormula <> "") Then
        'Return the sheet that this range is linked to
    End If
End Function
```

Can someone help me complete this function?  Keep in mind that this should work for internal links, external links, and links to sheets with a space in the name like "Sheet 1"

Edit:
In response to Siddharth Rout, I have previously tried

```
Function LinkedSheet(rgCell As Range) As Worksheet
'Returns the worksheet that the cell formula references
'Returns nothing if there's no formula
    Dim strFormula As String, sheetName As String

    strFormula = rgCell.Cells(1, 1).Formula

    If (strFormula <> "") Then
        'Return the sheet that this range is linked to
        sheetName = Mid(strFormula, 2, InStr(1, strFormula, "!") - 2)
        Set LinkedSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
    End If
End Function
```

which fails for sheets with a space in the name.  However, I was reluctant to post this because I feel there must be a better, more efficient way of tackling the problem and I didn't want to tunnel people's thought in the same direction that I went.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19348-Solved-Splitting-all-addresses-in-a-formula&p=142863#post142863

Comment: just as a fleeting thought: locate the possition of `!` in the formula String

Comment: If the sheet you reference has spaces in the name the value of sheetName will wrap the actual name in single ticks. You'll need to remove these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution

```
Function LinkedSheet(rgCell As Range) As Worksheet
'Returns the worksheet that the cell formula references
'Returns nothing if there's no formula
    Dim strFormula As String, sheetName As String

    strFormula = rgCell.Cells(1, 1).Formula

    If (strFormula <> "") Then
        'Return the sheet that this range is linked to
        If (InStr(1, strFormula, "='") = 0) Then
            sheetName = Mid(strFormula, 2, InStr(1, strFormula, "!") - 2)
        Else
            sheetName = Mid(strFormula, 3, InStr(1, strFormula, "!") - 4)
        End If
        Set LinkedSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
    End If
End Function
```

I'm not totally pleased with it.  I still think there may be better approaches, but this works.

Comment: @andy Wouldn't that fail if the sheet name had an apostrophe like "Andy's Sheet"?

Comment: You are correct. I deleted my comment. FWIW, Excel automatically escapes an apostrophe in a sheet name (with another apostrophe), so simply replacing them won't work.